# Android with opencv - image to grayscale

Tags: android, image, opencv, bitmap

I'm looking for simple example of app in Android which convert color image to grayscale using opencv.
I'm trying with thic code, but app crash after this line `Mat tmp = new Mat(bmp.getWidth(), bmp.getHeight(), CvType.CV_8U);`
.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    ImageView img=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView1);

    Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.ic_launcher);

    Mat tmp = new Mat(bmp.getWidth(), bmp.getHeight(), CvType.CV_8U);

    Utils.bitmapToMat(bmp, tmp);

    Imgproc.cvtColor(tmp, tmp, Imgproc.COLOR_RGB2GRAY);
    Imgproc.cvtColor(tmp, tmp, Imgproc.COLOR_RGB2GRAY,4);

    Utils.matToBitmap(tmp, bmp);
    img.setImageBitmap(bmp);
}
```

Comment: I assume this happens because both bmp.getWidth() and bmp.getHeight() return 0. I have not used OpenCV so far, so I am not sure if this really is the cause. However you can try putting some hard coded values there just to test if it is going to make any difference.

Answer (score 0):

Real quick way to do it. Without opencv.

```
 private Button button;
 private ImageView image;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
    image = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView1);


    button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            ColorMatrix matrix = new ColorMatrix();
            matrix.setSaturation(0);

            ColorMatrixColorFilter filter = new ColorMatrixColorFilter(matrix);
            image.setColorFilter(filter);


        }
    });
```

I just tried it, works for me.

edit: Check out the link here for official doc.
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/ColorMatrix.html#setSaturation(float)

Answer (score 0):

Your layout has not been laid out yet, while you are in `onCreate()`, that is why `bmp.getWidth()` and `bmp.getHeight()` return 0.
One way to do it is to override `onWindowFocusChanged()`

```
private ImageView img;
private boolean isFullyInitialized = false;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    img=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
}


@Override
public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus)
{
    super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);
    if (hasFocus && !isFullyInitialized)
    {
        isFullyInitialized = true;
        openCvCode();
    }
}

private void openCvCode()
{
    Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.ic_launcher);

    Mat tmp = new Mat(bmp.getWidth(), bmp.getHeight(), CvType.CV_8U);

    Utils.bitmapToMat(bmp, tmp);

    Imgproc.cvtColor(tmp, tmp, Imgproc.COLOR_RGB2GRAY);
    Imgproc.cvtColor(tmp, tmp, Imgproc.COLOR_RGB2GRAY,4);

    Utils.matToBitmap(tmp, bmp);
    img.setImageBitmap(bmp);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

ImageView img;
Bitmap bitmap;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    img=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView1);

    bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(this.getResources(), R.drawable.lena);

    if (!OpenCVLoader.initAsync(OpenCVLoader.OPENCV_VERSION_2_4_2, this, mOpenCVCallBack))
    {
        Log.e("TEST", "Cannot connect to OpenCV Manager");
    }


}

private BaseLoaderCallback  mOpenCVCallBack = new BaseLoaderCallback(this) {
    @Override
    public void onManagerConnected(int status) {
        switch (status) {
                case LoaderCallbackInterface.SUCCESS:
                {

                    Mat tmp = new Mat(bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight(),CvType.CV_8UC1);
                     // Convert
                    Utils.bitmapToMat(bitmap, tmp);

                    Mat gray = new Mat(bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight(),CvType.CV_8UC1);
                     // Conver the color
                    Imgproc.cvtColor(tmp, gray, Imgproc.COLOR_RGB2GRAY);
                     // Convert back to bitmap
                    Mat destination = new Mat(gray.rows(),gray.cols(),gray.type());

                    Imgproc.adaptiveThreshold(gray, destination, 255, Imgproc.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_MEAN_C, Imgproc.THRESH_BINARY_INV, 15, 4);

                    Utils.matToBitmap(destination, bitmap);
                    img.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

                } break;
                default:
                {
                    super.onManagerConnected(status);
                } break;
            }
    }
    };
```

}

Comment: Could you edit this answer to give more details what was the rootcause and why did you choose this solution? In that way it would be more helpful for other users that may have the same problem (i.e. the same rootcause) as you.